# Conditionally validate Dynamically generated Controls in Silverlight

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, mvvm

I am having a form with different type of controls like Text Box, Drop downs, Check box, Radio buttons etc. All these controls are loaded dynamically from database at run time.

**I want to perform validation on Text box on conditional basis. For example, If we have selected any value in drop down, then you must have to fill details in Text box. Otherwise text box details are not required.**

I am open to use database to perform this task and I am using MVVM pattern in my project.

Any help on this is highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have any properties in your ViewModel to represent the selected\entered values in these controls?

Comment: No, I am not having any property in ViewModel for selected control but one can get values from collection of all controls rendered on the page.

Comment: If you want to stick to MVVM principles, you should probably have something in your ViewModel that represents all the values for all controls so you can write some logic based on these values to disable\enable certain controls. How are you loading and instantiating them?

Comment: @fayilt: I am loading controls from database and instantiating them. My database holds values for controls datatype and variables. These controls are then added as child element in one of the usercontrol property that has binding with my view.

Comment: So you have a UserControls property on your ViewModel? Or is it declared elsewhere?

Comment: Yes, it is declared in ViewModel.

Answer (score 0):

(I started this as a comment, but it ended up being too long).

In theory you have access to all these controls and their values in your ViewModel.
Without knowing the specifics of your program, it's difficult to suggest anything useful, but in essence you need to expose some more properties from your ViewModel (probably boolean) which will be calculated based on the values in your controls. Then you need to bind IsEnabled properties on your controls to these new properties.

Sounds simple, but I think you have some architectural problems which will make it difficult to implement what I suggested above. In order for this to work and automatically update your controls whenever other controls' content change, your ViewModel needs to implement INotifyPropertyChanged and raise PropertyChanged event every time you update one of those boolean properties.

I think what you're trying to do could be achieved with ItemsControl and DataTemplates (and maybe DataTemplateSelectors). This will allow you to store "data" in your ViewModel (say List or something more specific) without referencing the actual Controls and the relevant DataTemplates will add the right controls for different data types you have in your ViewModel.